# JZZ's Standard MIDI File extension plays MIDI too slowly

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the code I used to initialize SMF. I don't really know what to try here, and I can't seem to find any other mention of it online.

```js
var fileplayer = new JZZ.MIDI.SMF(mididata).player();
fileplayer.connect(out);
fileplayer.play();
```

I tried using `midi-player-js` and `easy-midi` together but I couldn't find a nice way to play a MIDI that way.

The tempo is far too slow, as you can see here:

[Demonstration (MP4, H264/AAC)](http://uploads.kscott.cf/sharex/audio%20comparison.mp4)